# Trying to implement a bzero function gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i am trying to recode a bzero function which gives a segmentation fault, the problem is that i just implemented a function just like this(memset) using the same method and works great, and I can't see the difference between the two.
here are the codes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
    
    void    ft_bzero(void   *b, size_t len)
    {
        size_t i;
        unsigned char *mem;
        unsigned char s;
    
        mem = b;
        s = '\0';
        i = 0;
        while (i < len)
        {
            mem[i] = s;
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        char *b = "bzero";
        
        ft_bzero(b, 4);
        return (0);
    }
```

this is the memset implementation that works just fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
    
    void    *ft_memset(void *dest,  int c, size_t len)
    {
        size_t  i;
        unsigned char   s;
        unsigned char   *mem;
    
        mem = dest;
        s = c;
        i = 0;
        while (i < len)
        {
            mem[i] = s;
            i++;
        }
        return (dest);
    }
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
      
    int main()
    {
        char str[50] = "testing the c ft_memset";
        printf("\nBefore memset(): %s\n", str);
      
        ft_memset(str + 13, '.', 8*sizeof(char));
      
        printf("After memset():  %s", str);
        return (0);
    }
```

after trying for a while a saw that my testing was wrong, changing:

```
int main(void)
        {
            char *b = "bzero";
            
            ft_bzero(b, 4);
            return (0);
        }
```

to

```
int main(void)
{
    char b[5] = "bzero";
    
    ft_bzero(b, 4);
    return (0);
}
```

solved the issue.
thanks for all the help.

Comment: The function looks fine to me. The problem is probably with the array that you called it with.

Comment: Show us the testcase that segfaults.

Comment: Once you have `memset`, you can just define `bzero()` to call `memset(dest, 0, len);`

Comment: Interesting... I would expect that `void * ft_memset` that "works fine" to at least complain about the missing `return`. Are you sure you are showing the code you are running? What about a `main` that shows the one function "working fine" and the other crashing?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. They use wrong type for the index. It should be size_t not `unsigned int`.
2. The second function should return `void *` value but it does not return anything which is UB.

I would implement it this way (byte version):

```
void *ft_memset(void *dest,  int c, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *mem = dest;

    if(mem)
        while (len--)
            *mem++ = c;
    return dest;
}
```

or more complicated version:

```
#define UNSIGNEDSIZE 4

static_assert(sizeof(unsigned) == UNSIGNEDSIZE, "This function assumes 32 bit unsigned");

#define TAS(v,s) (((unsigned)((v) & 0xff)) << (s))

void *ft_memset(void *dest,  int c, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *mem = dest;
    unsigned *umem;
    unsigned uval = TAS(c,24) | TAS (c, 16) | TAS(c, 8) | TAS(c,0);
    unsigned trim = sizeof(unsigned) - ((uintptr_t)mem & (sizeof(unsigned) - 1));

    if(mem)
    {
        len -= trim;
        while (trim--)
            *mem++ = c;
        umem = (void *)mem;
        while(len > 3)
        {
            *umem++ = uval;
            len -= sizeof(unsigned);
        }
        mem = (void *)umem;
        while (len--)
            *mem++ = c;
    }   
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: 2 good catches, nice code reduction.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the funny part is that most popular compilers will optimize version 1 to the builtin function memset .

Comment: Looks like 2nd version could replace `unsigned` with `uint32_t` and then not need `static_assert()`.

Comment: The `unsigned int` error would have, at most, caused the code to loop, not a segmentation fault as the question reports. The failure to return a value is not undefined behavior by itself (the C standard permits a function declared with a return type to return without a value by flowing to its closing `}`). It could have been the problem if the caller used the return value (that is undefined behavior), but this turned out not to be the case. So this answer did not answer the question. Which is an example of why questions that need MREs but do not have them should be closed rather than answered.

Comment: Some tips: `TAS` is missing parentheses for `v`; `(v)` is of course preferred in macros. `uval` can also be initialized to `((uint32_t) c & 0xff) * 0x01010101u`. The code assumes the alignment requirement of `unsigned` equals its size, but `_Alignof` can be used to get the actual alignment requirement. The initialization of `trim` unnecessarily uses 4 instead of 0 when `mem` is aligned. `- (uintptr_t) mem & _Alignof(unsigned)-1` would produce 0, 1, 2, or 3, if the alignment requirement is 4. And, of course, the code violates the aliasing rule and so must be compiled appropriately.

Comment: @EricPostpischil good spot! amended